# How to list and access files between android application

Tags: android, apk, file-sharing

I have developed two application APK1 and APK2. i need to list files from APK1 to APK2 and access those files. but both apps are already in market. Using sharedUserId is not an option because of UID change.

Is this possible in Content provider

or

Is there is any other way of doing.

Comment: What does it matter that they are already on the market? If you want to add this feature you have to update both. So do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [contract class](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContractClasses).  I couldn't find a good online tutorial, I learned about them in [this](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845) course on udacity (it's free).